# Using dd to image a corrupted Windows disk?

Tags: hard-drive, windows, ntfs, disk-image

What is the proper way to use `dd` (or anything else - `asr`?) to create an image of a corrupted yet readable Windows disk?

If what I am using (see below) is correct, then is it possible that an image of a disk would not be mountable when the original disk is?

**Background info**:

The disk's file system is not readable on a Windows system: the disk shows up as "raw" in disk management. It is however readable in macOS (10.14) and I am able to copy individual files from it.

The goal however is to copy the entire disk if possible to a readable image and then work with that image (repair partition table, recover remaining files) rather than with the failing disk that I am afraid can quit at any moment.

Here is the command I've been using to image a 500GB Windows disk that came from a Dell computer and that has a number of bad blocks and apparently a corrupted partition table:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk3 of=/Volumes/exFAT_Vol/rdiskX.dmg bs=4M conv=noerror,sync
```

Copies fast (40MB/s via USB 2.0) but doesn't seem to create a correct (mountable) image: "no mountable file systems" when trying to mount it in Finder.

Some sources (e.g. [Recover a dead hard drive using dd](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050302225659382) from 2005) suggest using `bs=512` and it's in progress now - yet copies at around 4MB/s which will take more than a day to complete - and I am not even sure it'll work.

Some of the relevant info on the disk and its partitions:

```
Volume type : Physical Device
BSD device node : disk3
Connection : USB
Device tree path : IODeviceTree:/PCI0@0/XHC1@14
Writable : No
Is case-sensitive : No
Volume capacity : 500,107,862,016
Available space (Purgeable + Free) : 0
Purgeable space : 0
Free space : 0
Used space : 500,107,862,016
Owners enabled : No
Is encrypted : No
Can be verified : No
Can be repaired : No
Bootable : No
Journaled : No
Disk number : 3
Media name : Generic External Media
Media type : Generic
Ejectable : Yes
Solid state : No
S.M.A.R.T. status : Not Supported

Volume type : Physical Volume
BSD device node : disk3s2
Mount point : /Volumes/Untitled
File system : Windows NT File System (NTFS)
Connection : USB
Device tree path : IODeviceTree:/PCI0@0/XHC1@14
Writable : No
Is case-sensitive : No
File system UUID : AC8CB496-EAD2-47A2-BB36-2A981976BC2B
Volume capacity : 500,064,122,880
Available space (Purgeable + Free) : 373,903,597,568
Purgeable space : 0
Free space : 373,903,597,568
Used space : 126,160,525,312
File count : 176,730
Owners enabled : No
Is encrypted : No
System Integrity Protection supported : No
Can be verified : No
Can be repaired : No
Bootable : No
Journaled : No
Disk number : 3
Partition number : 2
Media name : 
Media type : Generic
Ejectable : Yes
Solid state : No
S.M.A.R.T. status : Not Supported
Parent disks : disk3
```

Comment: Just a couple more notes (I am in a hurry now so it's not a full answer): you should clone it with GNU ddrescue, you can browse it with Testdisk and you could even use RecuperaBit to read the contents (disclaimer: I am the author).

Comment: the question is about using dd - so I am assuming your comment implies `dd` is the wrong tool for the task? Could you say why?

Comment: Given that you talked about a disk "that has a number of bad blocks", the first thing that comes to mind is to use `ddrescue` instead of `dd`. Otherwise you would have to fully skip bad blocks (you also do not get easy stop/resume abilities with `dd` nor a nice progress status).

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I've done so far and the comments I've read on "[Recover a dead hard drive using dd](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050302225659382)":

- `dd` fails to image or clone damaged media to make the result equally mountable or readable, in multiple instances including mine;
- there isn't an alternate tool in stock macOS that can do that.

In more detail:

- The command I've been using in the question is the "proper" way - yet in many instances of working with damaged media, it does **not** create an image that like the original one, can be mounted and read. Basically, it fails at its task.
- There isn't an alternative within stock macOS (such as `ASR`) that can clone or image damaged yet readable media. `ASR` (or its GUI sibling, Disk Utility) will bail out once there is an I/O error such as bad blocks on the media.
- Haven't tried other tools that aren't part of macOS (such as `ddrescue` or `dd_rescue` mentioned in the linked article) - my answer is only about tools that are part of stock macOS.

The answer is based on multiple comments in "[Recover a dead hard drive using dd](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050302225659382)" that mirror my experience: `dd` completes yet the image can't be mounted. I.e. `dd` does not appear to have created a close enough image of the media.

Here is what I have tried:

- Use `sudo dd if=/dev/rdiskX of=/Volumes/exFAT_Vol/image.dmg bs=4M conv=noerror,sync` and `sudo dd if=/dev/rdiskXsY of=/Volumes/exFAT_Vol/image.dmg bs=4M conv=noerror,sync` to image the media. Neither image can be mounted, with errors such as "the following disks couldn't be opened: no mountable file systems".
- Use the resultant image to restore to a (healthy) physical media via `sudo dd if=/Volumes/exFAT_Vol/image.dmg of=/dev/rdiskZ bs=4M conv=noerror,sync` - with a similar result: the physical media can't be mounted, and unlike the original damaged one, doesn't display the partition information such as "`File system : Windows NT File System (NTFS)`".
- Attempt to use "First Aid" in "Disk Utility" to repair the images or the clones. None worked, with error messages such as:

  - `Fixing damaged partition map. The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.DiskManagement error -69874.) Operation failed…`.

What I haven't yet tried:

- Use `dd` with a different `bs=` value such as `512`, instead of `4m`. Takes too long.
- Use `dd` without the `conv=sync` option, i.e. just use `conv=noerror` one. (Just didn't have a chance to try it yet - each attempt takes 4-5 hours.)
- use `dd` with conventional rather than raw devices - e.g. `/dev/disk4` rather than `/dev/rdisk4`.
- Cloning directly from the damaged media to a healthy physical one, bypassing the imaging stage.
- Any other tools besides `dd`, Disk Utility, `asr`.

Hope this helps someone else in the same situation and really hope my answer is wrong: i.e. hope that there is a way to make `dd` work in this situation, to make mountable images off damaged yet readable / mountable media.